# Parse data with different ByteLength for a set of serial commands

Tags: node.js, serial-communication, node-serialport

I need to fetch the values for a set of commands which will run at regular intervals like

No of Set 1 Commands: 10

No of Set 2 Commands: 4

The problem is that **Set 1** Commands will give **2 Bytes** and **Set 2** Commands will provide **4 Bytes** of data which are independent HEX values and i need to perform seperate calculations on the response of both set of commands. These commands also will be sent at regular intervals. I am using the parser provided in the node serialport library

```
const ByteLength = require('@serialport/parser-byte-length');
parser = myPort.pipe(new ByteLength({ length: 2})); // pipe the serial stream to the parser
```

```
parser.on('data', console.log);
```

Bytelength when changed from 2 to 4 does not keep the data persistent like whenever the data event occurs it throws in the incoming buffer and start concatenating.

1. Is the approach correct?
2. How to choose variable ByteLength as there is only one global parser and serial port instance
3. Is setInterval a good fit for this situation